# django return foreign key object from queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

So I have three models

```
class Post(....

class Project(....

# have a many to many relationship
class ProjectPost(....
    post = ..... # foreignkey
    project = .... # foreignkey
```

The data set I want to select is a list of Post objects given a Project object.

This is what I tried:

```
posts_list = ProjectPost.objects.filter(project=project_object).select_related("post")
```

But this returns a list of ProjectPost objects rather than a list of Post objects.  What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to use the ManyToManyField()

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

You should do it like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    pass


class Project(models.Model):
    posts = models.ManyToManyField(Post)
```

And then, if you want to access the Posts of a Project, you can do

```
project_obj.posts.all()
```

You can use all the [Queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/) methods

If you want to access the projects of a posts you can do

```
post_obj.project_set.all()
```

Same as before, you can use all the Queryset methods.

If for any reason you want to do it that way, you could do:

```
post_list = ProjectPost.objects.filter(project=project_object).values('post')
```

Comment: When I did "posts_list = project_object.objects.all()", I got the error: Manager isn't accessible via Project instances.  Also I want to get the actual objects not just the ids, so ...values('post') by itself isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: Done, you should do project_obj.posts.all(). Sorry, my bad (really, i'm sorry)

Answer (score 1):

Came across this problem myself recently and this was how I solved it. Would love it if someone could comment on whether my solution is efficient.

```
project_posts = ProjectPost.objects.filter(project=project_object).select_related("post")
posts_lists = map(lambda post: project.post, project_posts)
```

Objects in posts_lists are now of the correct type.